# Log transformation function in R

Tags: r, regression, panel, transformation, negative-number

I would like to perform a panel data regression. Before that, I calculate the natural logarithm of my variables. Since some variables are negative, the logarithm produces some NAs.
At this point I would like to apply a transformation function so that no data is lost, basically like that:

> Ln(1+EBIT),if EBIT≥ 0 and -Ln(1-EBIT),if EBIT<0

Can anyone help me with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(EBIT) sign(EBIT)*log(1+abs(EBIT))
```

Comment: better than mine

Answer (score 0):

```r
ifelse(x>=0, log(1+x), -log(1-x))
```

Note this will still generate warnings since both branches of the `ifelse()` clause are executed.

(I hope you have a theoretical justification for this transformation ...)